# Adding my software to Debian

Tags: debian, apt, package-management, packaging, deb

How do you add a package to the official Debian APT repository? For example lets say I have a peice of software called quicktxtedit ,and I have a DEB file for it, and I want to add it to the offical repository for everyone. How would I do that?

Comment: Why the downvote? It is a legitimate question and a good fit for our site...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a number of steps involved in submitting your project to be added to Debian's archives. There are two main things you need to do.

1. Get your software into suitable shape for Debian. Debian is quite demanding 
   about what software is allowed in its archives. This includes:

   a) making sure your license terms are compatible with the [Debian Free Software Guidelines](https://www.debian.org/social_contract).

   b) making sure your Debian package conforms to [Debian Policy](https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/). [Lintian](https://lintian.debian.org/) is a tool to help you conform with 
   Debian policy, so you should try to fix Lintian errors and warnings 
   generated by your package. As part of doing this, you may have to work
   on your software build system. This can be a fair amount of effort in
   itself. You can get help with packaging from the #debian-mentors IRC channel on OFTC, and the debian-mentors mailing list.
2. Find a sponsor to upload your package. Places to ask include #debian-mentors 
   and the debian-mentors mailing list. It is a very good idea to have made some 
   progress with (1) before approaching a sponsor. Debian developers don't have 
   time to babysit new packagers, so you will get a better reception if you show 
   you have made some effort at the packaging end, even if the results are not 
   perfect. You should aim for a buildable binary package at least. Note
   that uploading your package to http://mentors.debian.net/ is an option, but 
   is not necessary. Potential sponsors need to be able to access your package; 
   so as long as it is somewhere public, that is fine. However, 
   http://mentors.debian.net/ does display information about your package in a 
   convenient form, and also provides a convenient interface for for people to 
   comment on your package. Your sponsor may be willing to take the time to help 
   you get the package into shape. At a minimum, he/she needs to review your 
   package.

If you have never done this before, I suggest you get started with (1) immediately. The process of getting your package into shape for Debian is useful and educational even if you never actually wind up getting your package into Debian. Bear in mind that you can make your package available in an unofficial apt repository.

Answer (score 1):

Submitting packages to Debian requires you to be a Debian developer. You will find more information about this in the [Debian Developer's Corner](https://www.debian.org/devel/).

I also came across [this submission to the debian-devel mailing list](https://lists.debian.org/debian-devel/1999/04/msg01606.html), in which you may find interesting information. You may navigate through the answers by using the **Next by thread** links at the bottom of each email.

Now, keep in mind that you can't just *put your software in the repositories*. You'll have to follow Debian's guidelines and rules. Here are a few links:

- [Debian's Organisational Structure](https://www.debian.org/intro/organization)
- [Joining Debian](https://www.debian.org/devel/join/)
- and last **but not least**, [the Debian Policy Manual](https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/).

<sub>And remember: *publishing free software does not mean you're free to do it any way you want. Freedom isn't to be confused with anarchy.*</sub>

Comment: "Submitting packages to Debian requires you to be a Debian developer" Incorrect. Anyone can submit packages to Debian; but you need a sponsor to upload it for you. There is also the category of [Debian Maintainer](https://wiki.debian.org/DebianMaintainer), which allows one limited upload rights.